# is MP4 a streaming protocol or file format?

Tags: android, mp4, google-cast

I am currently using Wowza to stream videos. I am currently trying to integrate Wowza, Android, and ChromeCast Device (CCD). According to this document, https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media, Google Cast supports the "MP4 protocol".

So, my question is this: is MP4 a streaming protocol, file format, or both?

In the ChromeCast Android demo applications, they simply pass a URL like this `http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4` as metadata to the CCD.

To me, this implies that no server is required to stream the MP4 file. Meaning, I won't even need Wowza as an intermediary party to stream.

Is this understanding correct?

It seems that the client player will then be responsible to interact with the MP4 file directly (e.g. seek, pause, stop, play, etc...).

Comment: have you tried it out? it sounds like you are correct..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you simply have an MP4 file, just pass its url and it should work fine, just like the samples (CastVideos) projects that we have on the Github.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Would have helped a lot more if you elaborated on whether serving an mp4 file is different from doing proper streaming and in what why. Also maybe point out the benefits of doing proper streaming.

Answer (score 18):

While you've already accepted an answer, and gotten your app to work (which was likely your ultimate goal), I thought it might be helpful to answer your question as well about what MP4 really is.

MP4 is a video container format; inside the MP4 container is video stream data (generally encoded in the H.264 format) and audio stream data (often encoded in the AAC format). The client player can interact with it directly because the Chromecast's browser has HTML5 video support for interpreting the MP4 container format and playing back the H.264 video and AAC audio, but it isn't "streaming" in the way that term is often used ... it's just downloading it from your web server in chunks and playing it back. There's nothing wrong with this if it's performing as you'd like (in fact, this is one of the big benefits of HTML5 video, that it doesn't need a streaming server backend), but if you actually want true media streaming (to leverage things such as adaptive bitrate switching, licensing, and so forth), you would have the MP4 file served via Wowza rather than via your web server.